# SHORTEST_PATH with several nodes and one edge in some graph tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, graph, gql

I have three tables to design actors paying in movies (films):

```
-- actors node table :
CREATE TABLE T_ACTEUR_ACT
(ACT_ID        INT PRIMARY KEY,
 ACT_PRENOM    VARCHAR(32),
 ACT_NOM       VARCHAR(50)) AS NODE;

-- movies node table (films)
CREATE TABLE T_FILM_FLM
(FLM_ID        INT PRIMARY KEY,
 FLM_TITRE     VARCHAR(250),
 FLM_ANNEE     SMALLINT) AS NODE;

-- playing edge
CREATE TABLE T_JOUE_JOU (JOU_INTERPRETE VARCHAR(250)) AS EDGE;
GO
```

I would like to know how to write a Graph Query to find the shortest social distance between Cary Grant and James Mason...

Every queries I have tried does not work...

```
SELECT ACTOR, chemin, Q.LastNode AS FRIEND
FROM
(
SELECT acteur0.ACT_PRENOM + acteur0.ACT_NOM AS ACTOR, 
         STRING_AGG(CONCAT(acteurN.ACT_PRENOM, ' ', acteurN.ACT_NOM), '->') 
          WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS chemin,
         LAST_VALUE(CONCAT(acteurN.ACT_PRENOM, ' ', acteurN.ACT_NOM)) 
          WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS LastNode
FROM   T_ACTEUR_ACT AS acteur0,
         T_JOUE_JOU FOR PATH AS joue,
       T_FILM_FLM FOR PATH as film,
       T_JOUE_JOU FOR PATH AS joue2,
         T_ACTEUR_ACT FOR PATH AS acteurN
WHERE  MATCH(SHORTEST_PATH( acteur0 ( - (joue) -> film - (joue2) -> acteurN ) + ) )
  AND  acteur0.ACT_PRENOM = 'Cary' AND acteur0.ACT_NOM = 'Grant'
  AND  acteurN.ACT_PRENOM <> 'Cary' AND acteurN.ACT_NOM <> 'Grant'
) AS G
WHERE G.LastNode = 'James Mason'
```

The result is 3exceptions :

Msg 13961, Niveau 16, État 1...

The alias or identifier 'acteurN.ACT_PRENOM' cannot be used in the select list, order by, group by, or having context.

Msg 13961, Niveau 16, État 1...

The alias or identifier 'acteurN.ACT_NOM' cannot be used in the select list, order by, group by, or having context.

*Thoses are relative to the last two rows or the subquery...*

Msg 4104, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne ...

The multi-part identifier "Q.LastNode" could not be bound.

I have try another approach for the subquery :

```
SELECT acteur0.ACT_PRENOM, acteur0.ACT_NOM, 
         STRING_AGG(CONCAT(acteurN.ACT_PRENOM, ' ', acteurN.ACT_NOM), '->') 
          WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS chemin,
         LAST_VALUE(CONCAT(acteurN.ACT_PRENOM, ' ', acteurN.ACT_NOM)) 
          WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS LastNode
FROM   T_ACTEUR_ACT AS acteur0,
         T_JOUE_JOU FOR PATH AS joue,
       T_FILM_FLM FOR PATH as film,
       T_JOUE_JOU FOR PATH AS joue2,
         T_ACTEUR_ACT FOR PATH AS acteurN
WHERE  MATCH(SHORTEST_PATH(acteur0 ( - (joue) -> film)+)
             AND 
             SHORTEST_PATH(LAST_NODE(film)(-(joue2) -> acteurN)+))
    AND acteur0.ACT_PRENOM = 'Cary' AND acteur0.ACT_NOM = 'Grant'
   AND acteurN.ACT_PRENOM <> 'Cary' AND acteurN.ACT_NOM <> 'Grant'
```

But the same two exceptions (The alias or identifier ... cannot be used in the select list...)

Here is my test set :

```
-- premier film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(1, 'Rebecca', 1940);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10001, 'Laurence', 'Olivier'),
(10002, 'Joan', 'Fontaine'),
(10003, 'Georges', 'Sanders');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10001), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 1), 'George Fortescue Maximilien de Winter'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10002), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 1), 'Mrs de Winter'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10003), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 1), 'Jack Favell');
GO

-- second film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(2, 'Correspondant 17', 1940);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10004, 'Joel', 'McCrea'),
(10005, 'Laraine', 'Day'),
(10006, 'Herbert', 'Marshall');


INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10004), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 2), 'John Jones / Huntley Haverstock'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10005), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 2), 'Carol Fisher'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10006), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 2), 'Stephen Fisher'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10003), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 2), 'Scott Ffolliott');
GO

-- 3e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(3, 'Soupçons', 1941);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10007, 'Cary', 'Grant'),
(10014, 'Leo', 'G. Caroll');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10002), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 3), 'Lina McLaidlaw Aysgarth'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10007), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 3), 'Johnnie Aysgarth'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10014), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 3), 'capitaine George Melbeck')
;


-- 4e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(4, 'L''Ombre d''un doute', 1943);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10008, 'Joseph', 'Cotten'),
(10017, 'Teresa', 'Wright');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10008), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 4), 'Charlie Oakley'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10017), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 4), 'Charlotte Newton');

-- 5e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(5, 'La Maison du docteur Edwardes', 1945);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10009, 'Gregory', 'Peck'),
(10010, 'Ingrid', 'Bergman');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10009), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 5), 'John Ballantine / Dr Anthony Edwardes / John Brown'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10010), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 5), 'Dr Constance Petersen'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10014), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 5), 'Dr Murchinson');


-- 6e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(6, 'Les Enchaînés', 1946);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10018, 'Claude', 'Rains');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10007), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 6), 'T.R. Devlin'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10010), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 6), 'Alicia Huberman'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10018), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 6), 'Alexander Sebastian');


-- 7e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(7, 'Le Procès Paradine', 1947);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10011, 'Charles', 'Laughton'),
(10019, 'Ann', 'Todd'),
(10020, 'Louis', 'Jourdan');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10009), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 7), 'Anthony Keane'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10011), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 7), 'Lord Thomas Horfield (juge)'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10019), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 7), 'Gay Keane'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10020), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 7), 'André Latour'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10014), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 7), 'Sir Joseph');

-- 8e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(8, 'la Corde', 1948);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10012, 'Farley', 'Granger'),
(10013, 'James', 'Stewart');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10012), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 8), 'Philip Morgan'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10013), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 8), 'Rupert Cadell');


-- 9e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(9, 'Les Amants du Capricorne', 1949);

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10008), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 9), 'Sam Flusky'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10010), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 9), 'Henrietta Flusky');

-- 10e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(10, 'L''Inconnu du Nord-Express', 1951);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10021, 'Ruth', 'Roman'),
(10022, 'Robert', 'Walker'),
(10023, 'Patricia', 'Hitchcock');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10012), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 10), 'Guy Haines'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10014), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 10), 'sénateur Morton'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10021), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 10), 'Anne Morton'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10022), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 10), 'Bruno Antony'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10023), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 10), 'Barbara Morton');


-- 11e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(11, 'Le crime était presque parfait', 1954);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10015, 'Ray', 'Milland'),
(10016, 'Grace', 'Kelly'),
(10024, 'Robert', 'Cummings'),
(10025, 'John', 'Williams');
;

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10015), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 11), 'Tony Wendice'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10016), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 11), 'Margot Wendice'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10024), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 11), 'Mark Halliday'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10025), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 11), 'inspecteur Hubbard');

-- 12e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(12, 'Fenêtre sur cour', 1954);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10026, 'Raymond', 'Burr');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10013), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 12), 'Jeff Jefferies'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10016), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 12), 'Lisa Carol Fremont'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10026), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 12), 'Lars Thorwald');

-- 13e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(13, 'La Main au collet', 1955);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10027, 'Charles', 'Vanel'),
(10028, 'Brigitte', 'Auber'),
(10029, 'Jessie', 'Royce Landis');


INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10007), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 13), 'Georges Robert dit « le Chat » (John Robie dans la version originale)'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10016), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 13), 'Frances Stevens'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10027), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 13), 'Bertani'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10028), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 13), 'Danielle Foussard'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10029), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 13), 'Jessie Stevens'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10025), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 13), 'H. H. Hughson');

-- 14e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(14, 'L''Homme qui en savait trop', 1956);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10030, 'Doris', 'Day'),
(10031, 'Daniel', 'Gélin');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10007), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 14), 'docteur Ben McKenna'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10030), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 14), 'Dorothée McKenna'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10031), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 14), 'Louis Bernard');

-- 15e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(15, 'Sueurs froides', 1959);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10032, 'Kim', 'Novak');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10013), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 15), 'John Ferguson'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10032), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 15), 'Madeleine Elster / Judy Barton');

-- 16e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(16, 'La Mort aux trousses', 1959);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10033, 'Eva Marie', 'Saint'),
(10034, 'James', 'Mason'),
(10035, 'Martin', 'Landau');;

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10007), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 16), 'Roger Thornhill'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10033), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 16), 'Eve Kendall'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10034), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 16), 'Philip Vandamm'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10035), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 16), 'Leonard'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10029), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 16), 'Clara Thornhill'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10014), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 16), 'le professeur');


-- 17e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(17, 'Psychose', 1960);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10036, 'Antony', 'Perkins'),
(10037, 'Janet', 'Leigh');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10036), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 17), 'Norman Bates'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10037), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 17), 'Marion Crane'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10023), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 17), 'Caroline (la secrétaire)');

-- 18e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(18, 'Les oiseaux', 1963);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10038, 'Rod', 'Taylor'),
(10039, 'Tippi', 'Hedren');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10038), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 18), 'Mitch Brenner'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10039), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 18), 'Melanie Daniels');


-- 19e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(19, 'Pas de printemps pour Marnie', 1964);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10040, 'Sean', 'Connery');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10038), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 19), 'Mark Rutland'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10039), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 19), 'Marnie Edgar / Margaret Edgar / Peggy Nicholson / Mary Taylor / Marion Holland');

-- 20e film

INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(20, 'Le rideau déchiré', 1966);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10041, 'Paul', 'Newman'),
(10042, 'Julie', 'Andrews');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10041), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 20), 'professeur Michael Armstrong'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10042), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 20), 'docteur Sarah Louise Sherman');

-- 21e film
INSERT INTO T_FILM_FLM VALUES
(21, 'L''étau', 1969);

INSERT INTO T_ACTEUR_ACT VALUES
(10043, 'Frédérick', 'Stafford'),
(10044, 'Dany', 'Robin'),
(10045, 'Claude', 'Jade'),
(10046, 'Michel', 'Piccoli'),
(10047, 'Philippe', 'Noiret');

INSERT INTO T_JOUE_JOU VALUES
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10043), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 21), 'André Devereaux'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10044), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 21), 'Nicole Devereaux'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10045), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 21), 'Michèle Picard'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10046), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 21), 'Jacques Granville'),
((SELECT $node_id FROM T_ACTEUR_ACT WHERE ACT_ID = 10047), (SELECT $node_id FROM T_FILM_FLM WHERE FLM_ID = 21), 'Henri Jarré');
```

Which is relative to alfred Hitchcock's main films...

Comment: "Q.LastNode" could not be bound. -> the derived table is aliased as G the column is qualified with Q. The graph is directional from->to, actors to film, (but not to->from, not film to actors): MATCH(acteur-(joue)->film) returns actors who play in film but MATCH(film-(joue)->acteur) or MATCH(acteur<-(joue)-film) return nothing. You could insert from: film, to:actor into the edge table to link films to actors. It is possible to filter a path table before the recursion: `(select * from T_ACTEUR_ACT where ACT_PRENOM <> 'Cary' AND ACT_NOM <> 'Grant') FOR PATH AS acteurN`

Comment: Adjusted data for recursion (cary grant played in film1 with actor1 who played in film2 with actor2 .. in filmX with 'James Mason': https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb1104c7f3e52573763edbe1adad3cfb. (The filter where ACT_PRENOM <> 'Cary' .. in the path acteurN is not actually needed)

Comment: I have deleted "(select * from T_ACTEUR_ACT where ACT_PRENOM <> 'Cary' AND ACT_NOM <> 'Grant')" and replace by the name of the table, and try with some more complex path and it works... Thanks ! Do you have any website which describes the complete syntax of MATCH and SHORTEST_PATH functions ? (with some examples)

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @lptr is good !

I just simplify as :

```
WITH
T_SEARCH_PATH AS
(
SELECT acteur0.ACT_PRENOM + ' '+ acteur0.ACT_NOM AS ACTOR, 
       STRING_AGG(CONCAT(acteurN.ACT_PRENOM, ' ', acteurN.ACT_NOM, ' : ', film.FLM_TITRE), ' -> ') 
          WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS path_to,
       LAST_VALUE(CONCAT(acteurN.ACT_PRENOM, ' ', acteurN.ACT_NOM)) 
          WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS LastNode
FROM   T_ACTEUR_ACT AS acteur0,
       T_JOUE_JOU FOR PATH AS joue,
       T_FILM_FLM FOR PATH as film,
       T_JOUE_JOU FOR PATH AS joue2,
       T_ACTEUR_ACT FOR PATH AS acteurN
WHERE  MATCH(SHORTEST_PATH( acteur0 ( - (joue) -> film - (joue2) -> acteurN ) + ) )
  AND  acteur0.ACT_PRENOM = 'Cary' AND acteur0.ACT_NOM = 'Grant'
)
SELECT ACTOR, path_to, LastNode AS FRIEND
FROM   T_SEARCH_PATH
WHERE  LastNode = 'Gregory Peck';
```

Which give me an answer like :

```
ACTOR        path_to                                                                          FRIEND
------------ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------
Cary Grant   Ingrid Bergman : Les Enchaînés -> Gregory Peck : La Maison du docteur Edwardes   Gregory Peck
```